# Buffer() в кодировке Windows-1252

Tags: javascript, node.js, кодировка, iconv

Привет.

```
BattleNode.prototype.commandPacket = function (command) {  

  var data = new Buffer(command.length + 3);
  data.writeUInt8(0xFF, 0);
  data.writeUInt8(BE_COMMAND_PACKET, 1);
  data.writeUInt8(this.sequence, 2);
  data.write(command, 3);

  this.sequence = (this.sequence >= 255) ? 0 : this.sequence + 1;

  var packet = this.createBEPacket(data);

  return packet;

}

BattleNode.prototype.createBEPacket = function(payload) {

  var packet = new Buffer(payload.length + 6); // payload + header
  var header = new Buffer([0x42, 0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]);
  var crc = crc32(payload);

  header.writeInt32BE(crc.readInt32LE(0), 2);

  header.copy(packet);
  payload.copy(packet, 6);

  return packet;

}
```

// Переменная command приходит уже в кодировке Windows-1252. И нужно чтобы буффер создавался с этой же кодировкой.

Пробовал через iconv-lite. Ничего вразумительного не вышло. Может есть идеи?

Comment: А что внутри command  если сделать console.log() ??

Comment: #kick ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚

Comment: а typeof command

Comment: Для чего спрашиваете? =) Команда содержит String =)

Comment: а если так сделать на второй строчке var data = iconv.encode(command, 'win1251');

Comment: Почему вы все время пишете 1251? =) Если мне нужно 1252.  И так, как вы написали не подходит.

Comment: А зачем 1252? там же русских букв нету

Comment: Информация приходит в этой кодировке и я должен серверу отправить её обратно в таком же ввиде, иначе она не воспримется, дело в этом.

Comment: попробуйте 1251, 1252 это немецкие и подобные языки, не думаю что реально там используется 1252

Comment: @vnn198 windows1252

Answer (score 0):

Начнём по порядку, я не гуру js но, Buffer не имеет кодировки ,это просто набор байтов, что касается iconv-lite то он прекрасно преобразует строки между кодировками, например этот код преобразует string в Buffer с win1251

```
var string = iconv.encode("Тут строка, большая строка", 'win1251');
```

Comment: Тогда вопрос, как мне получить точную длину строки command, если это строка в win1252 кодировке?

Comment: надо её преобразовать в utf8, и дальше стандартными методами JS

Comment: Дело в том, что сокет должен отправить строку именно в win1252 кодировке до сервера.